# What counts as being "wounded" for the purpose of the rules on recovering a point of Hope?

Tags: the-one-ring

In *The One Ring* game, players are allowed to recover a point of Hope if their Fellowship focus is not wounded during the session. The issue is that the rules don't seem to state if they mean the Wounded condition (which involves a successful edge hit with armor failing to overcome injury), or simply having taken damage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page 81 of the core rulebook first mentions using a Fellowship focus to recover Hope without using Fellowship points:

> Every player is free to indicate one companion of his choice as his focus. [...] A Fellowship focus lets a character recover Hope without spending Fellowship (at the risk of gaining Shadow should the focus be harmed or killed); see page 133.

As mentioned, pages 133-134 detail the mechanics for a Fellowship focus, including the rules on recovering Hope or gaining Shadow points depending on what happens to them. Under the heading "As a Source of Hope", it says:

> The presence of a Fellowship focus affects the way a character recovers Hope:
>
> A player-hero recovers 1 point of Hope at the end of a session if his Fellowship focus didn’t become Wounded, Poisoned, Miserable, or was harmed in any other way the Loremaster considers serious (such as imprisoned by Orcs) during play, and is in the same location as them.
>
> A character gains 1 point of Shadow at the end of the session if his Fellowship focus was Wounded, or 3 points if the focus was killed.

The capitalization here indicates that the game is referring to the Wounded, Poisoned, and Miserable conditions, as detailed on pages 128-130. Note, however, that the requirement is not limited to those 3 conditions; the rule gives the Loremaster leeway to decree that "serious harm" to a character prevents recovering a Hope point as well.

As long as the player's chosen Fellowship focus is in the same location at the end of the session, and did not suffer one of those three conditions or otherwise suffer serious harm during play, the player's character can recover 1 point of Hope. If the chosen Fellowship focus did suffer the Wounded condition, the player-hero does not recover a point of Hope, and also gains 1 point of Shadow. If the chosen Fellowship focus was killed, they gain 3 points of Shadow instead.